# How do I cause a cross-platform (IE and Chrome at least) popup from inside an SVG?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, svg

I have code that generates SVG that was developed for IE and the Adobe SVG Viewer.  The Adobe SVG Viewer has a custom function called `browserEval` (see http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/994) that is being used to cause the browser to eval a window.open() call.  This doesn't work in Chrome's native SVG renderer (and I haven't tried Firefox).

How can I rewrite this popup function to work properly in all modern SVG-supporting browsers?  This original one works in IE but not Chrome:

```
function popUp(loc) { 
    browserEval("window.open('"+loc+"','_blank', 
        'width=1000,height=780,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, 
        status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no')");
}
```

I tried this which works in Chrome but causes an error about number of arguments in IE:

```
var browserEvalCrossBrowser = (typeof(browserEval)=='undefined') ?
    function(x) { eval(x); } : browserEval;

function popUp(loc) { 
    browserEvalCrossBrowser("window.open('"+loc+"','_blank',
        'width=1000,height=780,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,
        status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no')");
}
```

Comment: Something else that looks like an error: Your string in double-quotes is multiline, and that's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a single quote before the word "width", which is a syntax error.

Aside from that, apparently there is a bug in browserEval that causes this error (http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/9063). Have you tried `function(x) { browserEval(x); }` instead of `browserEval`?

Comment: That's a transcription error, it was correct in the code.  Thanks for pointing it out, I'll correct it.